What may be preventing access to unpriviledge port on this service unit?
Trying to start nginx via systemd service, I think I gave all permissions it need for unpriviledged ports, even added CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE, but still get:

nginx[122819]: 2024/09/01 04:11:38 [emerg] 122819#122819: bind() to 127.0.0.1:8000 failed (1: Operation not permitted)

the user can run netcat -l 8000 just fine. SELinux is disabled.
Here's the list of things i'm limiting on the unit.
  NAME                                                        DESCRIPTION                                                                                         EXPOSURE
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@swap                                     System call allow list defined for service, and @swap is not included                               
✗ SystemCallFilter=~@resources                                System call allow list defined for service, and @resources is included (e.g. ioprio_set is allowed)      0.2
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@reboot                                   System call allow list defined for service, and @reboot is not included                             
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@raw-io                                   System call allow list defined for service, and @raw-io is not included                             
✗ SystemCallFilter=~@privileged                               System call allow list defined for service, and @privileged is included (e.g. chown is allowed)          0.2
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@obsolete                                 System call allow list defined for service, and @obsolete is not included                           
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@mount                                    System call allow list defined for service, and @mount is not included                              
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@module                                   System call allow list defined for service, and @module is not included                             
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@debug                                    System call allow list defined for service, and @debug is not included                              
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@cpu-emulation                            System call allow list defined for service, and @cpu-emulation is not included                      
✓ SystemCallFilter=~@clock                                    System call allow list defined for service, and @clock is not included                              
✓ RemoveIPC=                                                  Service user cannot leave SysV IPC objects around                                                   
✗ RootDirectory=/RootImage=                                   Service runs within the host's root directory                                                            0.1
✓ User=/DynamicUser=                                          Service runs under a static non-root user identity                                                  
✓ RestrictRealtime=                                           Service realtime scheduling access is restricted                                                    
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_TIME                         Service processes cannot change the system clock                                                    
✓ NoNewPrivileges=                                            Service processes cannot acquire new privileges                                                     
✗ AmbientCapabilities=                                        Service process receives ambient capabilities                                                            0.1
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_BPF                              Service may not load BPF programs                                                                   
✓ SystemCallArchitectures=                                    Service may execute system calls only with native ABI                                               
✗ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_(CHOWN|FSETID|SETFCAP)           Service may change file ownership/access mode/capabilities unrestricted                                  0.2
✗ RestrictAddressFamilies=~AF_(INET|INET6)                    Service may allocate Internet sockets                                                                    0.3
✗ ProtectSystem=                                              Service has very limited write access to the OS file hierarchy                                           0.1
✓ ProtectProc=                                                Service has restricted access to process tree (/proc hidepid=)                                      
✓ SupplementaryGroups=                                        Service has no supplementary groups                                                                 
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_RAWIO                        Service has no raw I/O access                                                                       
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_PTRACE                       Service has no ptrace() debugging abilities                                                         
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_(NICE|RESOURCE)              Service has no privileges to change resource use parameters                                         
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_NET_ADMIN                        Service has no network configuration privileges                                                     
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_AUDIT_*                          Service has no audit subsystem access                                                               
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_ADMIN                        Service has no administrator privileges                                                             
✓ PrivateNetwork=                                             Service has no access to the host's network                                                         
✓ PrivateTmp=                                                 Service has no access to other software's temporary files                                           
✓ ProcSubset=                                                 Service has no access to non-process /proc files (/proc subset=)                                    
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYSLOG                           Service has no access to kernel logging                                                             
✓ PrivateDevices=                                             Service has no access to hardware devices                                                           
✗ ProtectHome=                                                Service has full access to home directories                                                              0.2
✗ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_NET_(BIND_SERVICE|BROADCAST|RAW) Service has elevated networking privileges                                                               0.1
✗ DeviceAllow=                                                Service has a device ACL with some special devices: char-rtc:r                                           0.1
✓ KeyringMode=                                                Service doesn't share key material with other services                                              
✓ Delegate=                                                   Service does not maintain its own delegated control group subtree                                   
✓ PrivateUsers=                                               Service does not have access to other users                                                         
✗ IPAddressDeny=                                              Service defines IP address allow list with non-localhost entries                                         0.1
✓ NotifyAccess=                                               Service child processes cannot alter service state                                                  
✓ ProtectClock=                                               Service cannot write to the hardware clock or system clock                                          
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_PACCT                        Service cannot use acct()                                                                           
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_KILL                             Service cannot send UNIX signals to arbitrary processes                                             
✓ ProtectKernelLogs=                                          Service cannot read from or write to the kernel log ring buffer                                     
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_WAKE_ALARM                       Service cannot program timers that wake up the system                                               
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_(DAC_*|FOWNER|IPC_OWNER)         Service cannot override UNIX file/IPC permission checks                                             
✓ ProtectControlGroups=                                       Service cannot modify the control group file system                                                 
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE                  Service cannot mark files immutable                                                                 
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_IPC_LOCK                         Service cannot lock memory into RAM                                                                 
✓ ProtectKernelModules=                                       Service cannot load or read kernel modules                                                          
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_MODULE                       Service cannot load kernel modules                                                                  
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG                   Service cannot issue vhangup()                                                                      
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_BOOT                         Service cannot issue reboot()                                                                       
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_CHROOT                       Service cannot issue chroot()                                                                       
✓ PrivateMounts=                                              Service cannot install system mounts                                                                
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND                    Service cannot establish wake locks                                                                 
✓ MemoryDenyWriteExecute=                                     Service cannot create writable executable memory mappings                                           
✓ RestrictNamespaces=~user                                    Service cannot create user namespaces                                                               
✓ RestrictNamespaces=~pid                                     Service cannot create process namespaces                                                            
✓ RestrictNamespaces=~net                                     Service cannot create network namespaces                                                            
✓ RestrictNamespaces=~uts                                     Service cannot create hostname namespaces                                                           
✓ RestrictNamespaces=~mnt                                     Service cannot create file system namespaces                                                        
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_LEASE                            Service cannot create file leases                                                                   
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_MKNOD                            Service cannot create device nodes                                                                  
✓ RestrictNamespaces=~cgroup                                  Service cannot create cgroup namespaces                                                             
✓ RestrictNamespaces=~ipc                                     Service cannot create IPC namespaces                                                                
✓ ProtectHostname=                                            Service cannot change system host/domainname                                                        
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SET(UID|GID|PCAP)                Service cannot change UID/GID identities/capabilities                                               
✓ LockPersonality=                                            Service cannot change ABI personality                                                               
✓ ProtectKernelTunables=                                      Service cannot alter kernel tunables (/proc/sys, …)                                                 
✓ RestrictAddressFamilies=~AF_PACKET                          Service cannot allocate packet sockets                                                              
✓ RestrictAddressFamilies=~AF_NETLINK                         Service cannot allocate netlink sockets                                                             
✓ RestrictAddressFamilies=~AF_UNIX                            Service cannot allocate local sockets                                                               
✓ RestrictAddressFamilies=~…                                  Service cannot allocate exotic sockets                                                              
✓ CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_MAC_*                            Service cannot adjust SMACK MAC                                                                     
✓ RestrictSUIDSGID=                                           SUID/SGID file creation by service is restricted                                                    
✓ UMask=                                                      Files created by service are accessible only by service's own user by default                       

→ Overall exposure level for nginx.service: 1.3 OK 

On nginx.conf I only have one single server: http.server.listen: "127.0.0.1:8000"
 # systemctl show nginx.service 
Type=forking
ExitType=main
Restart=on-failure
RestartMode=normal
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
NotifyAccess=none
RestartUSec=100ms
RestartSteps=0
RestartMaxDelayUSec=infinity
RestartUSecNext=100ms
TimeoutStartUSec=1min 30s
TimeoutStopUSec=5s
TimeoutAbortUSec=5s
TimeoutStartFailureMode=terminate
TimeoutStopFailureMode=terminate
RuntimeMaxUSec=infinity
RuntimeRandomizedExtraUSec=0
WatchdogUSec=0
WatchdogTimestampMonotonic=0
RootDirectoryStartOnly=no
RemainAfterExit=no
GuessMainPID=yes
MainPID=0
ControlPID=0
FileDescriptorStoreMax=0
NFileDescriptorStore=0
FileDescriptorStorePreserve=restart
StatusErrno=0
Result=exit-code
ReloadResult=success
CleanResult=success
UID=[not set]
GID=[not set]
NRestarts=5
OOMPolicy=stop
ReloadSignal=1
ExecMainStartTimestampMonotonic=0
ExecMainExitTimestampMonotonic=0
ExecMainHandoffTimestampMonotonic=0
ExecMainPID=0
ExecMainCode=0
ExecMainStatus=0
ExecStart={ path=/usr/bin/nginx ; argv[]=/usr/bin/nginx ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }
ExecStartEx={ path=/usr/bin/nginx ; argv[]=/usr/bin/nginx ; flags= ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }
ExecReload={ path=/usr/bin/nginx ; argv[]=/usr/bin/nginx -s reload ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }
ExecReloadEx={ path=/usr/bin/nginx ; argv[]=/usr/bin/nginx -s reload ; flags= ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }
ExecStopPost={ path=/bin/sh ; argv[]=/bin/sh -c if [ "$$EXIT_STATUS" = 2 ]; then echo alert; fi ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(n>
ExecStopPostEx={ path=/bin/sh ; argv[]=/bin/sh -c if [ "$$EXIT_STATUS" = 2 ]; then echo alert; fi ; flags= ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(null) ; s>
Slice=system.slice
ControlGroupId=0
MemoryCurrent=[not set]
MemoryPeak=[not set]
MemorySwapCurrent=[not set]
MemorySwapPeak=[not set]
MemoryZSwapCurrent=[not set]
MemoryAvailable=6306099200
EffectiveMemoryMax=7204151296
EffectiveMemoryHigh=7204151296
CPUUsageNSec=[not set]
TasksCurrent=[not set]
EffectiveTasksMax=8215
IPIngressBytes=[no data]
IPIngressPackets=[no data]
IPEgressBytes=[no data]
IPEgressPackets=[no data]
IOReadBytes=[not set]
IOReadOperations=[not set]
IOWriteBytes=[not set]
IOWriteOperations=[not set]
Delegate=no
CPUAccounting=yes
CPUWeight=[not set]
StartupCPUWeight=[not set]
CPUShares=[not set]
StartupCPUShares=[not set]
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPeriodUSec=infinity
IOAccounting=no
IOWeight=[not set]
StartupIOWeight=[not set]
BlockIOAccounting=no
BlockIOWeight=[not set]
StartupBlockIOWeight=[not set]
MemoryAccounting=yes
DefaultMemoryLow=0
DefaultStartupMemoryLow=0
DefaultMemoryMin=0
MemoryMin=0
MemoryLow=0
StartupMemoryLow=0
MemoryHigh=infinity
StartupMemoryHigh=infinity
MemoryMax=infinity
StartupMemoryMax=infinity
MemorySwapMax=infinity
StartupMemorySwapMax=infinity
MemoryZSwapMax=infinity
StartupMemoryZSwapMax=infinity
MemoryZSwapWriteback=yes
MemoryLimit=infinity
DevicePolicy=closed
DeviceAllow=char-rtc r
TasksAccounting=yes
TasksMax=8215
IPAccounting=no
ManagedOOMSwap=auto
ManagedOOMMemoryPressure=auto
ManagedOOMMemoryPressureLimit=0
ManagedOOMPreference=none
SocketBindAllow=tcp443
SocketBindAllow=tcp80
SocketBindDeny=any
MemoryPressureWatch=auto
MemoryPressureThresholdUSec=200ms
CoredumpReceive=no
UMask=0077
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitCPUSoft=infinity
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitFSIZESoft=infinity
LimitDATA=infinity
LimitDATASoft=infinity
LimitSTACK=infinity
LimitSTACKSoft=8388608
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitCORESoft=infinity
LimitRSS=infinity
LimitRSSSoft=infinity
LimitNOFILE=524288
LimitNOFILESoft=1024
LimitAS=infinity
LimitASSoft=infinity
LimitNPROC=27386
LimitNPROCSoft=27386
LimitMEMLOCK=8388608
LimitMEMLOCKSoft=8388608
LimitLOCKS=infinity
LimitLOCKSSoft=infinity
LimitSIGPENDING=27386
LimitSIGPENDINGSoft=27386
LimitMSGQUEUE=819200
LimitMSGQUEUESoft=819200
LimitNICE=0
LimitNICESoft=0
LimitRTPRIO=0
LimitRTPRIOSoft=0
LimitRTTIME=infinity
LimitRTTIMESoft=infinity
WorkingDirectory=/var/log/nginx
RootEphemeral=no
OOMScoreAdjust=0
CoredumpFilter=0x33
Nice=0
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=4
CPUSchedulingPolicy=0
CPUSchedulingPriority=0
CPUAffinityFromNUMA=no
NUMAPolicy=n/a
TimerSlackNSec=50000
CPUSchedulingResetOnFork=no
NonBlocking=no
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
TTYReset=no
TTYVHangup=no
TTYVTDisallocate=no
SyslogPriority=27
SyslogLevelPrefix=yes
SyslogLevel=3
SyslogFacility=3
LogLevelMax=-1
LogRateLimitIntervalUSec=0
LogRateLimitBurst=0
SecureBits=0
CapabilityBoundingSet=cap_chown cap_net_bind_service
AmbientCapabilities=cap_net_bind_service
User=http
DynamicUser=no
SetLoginEnvironment=yes
RemoveIPC=yes
ReadWritePaths=/var/log/nginx -/run/nginx.pid -/run/lock/nginx.lock /dev/null /dev/zero /tmp /var/log/nginx /var/lib/nginx
ReadOnlyPaths=/ /home/http
InaccessiblePaths=/root /run/user
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
ProtectClock=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelLogs=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
PrivateNetwork=yes
PrivateUsers=yes
PrivateMounts=no
PrivateIPC=no
ProtectHome=no
ProtectSystem=full
SameProcessGroup=no
UtmpMode=init
IgnoreSIGPIPE=yes
NoNewPrivileges=yes
SystemCallFilter=_llseek _newselect accept accept4 access add_key alarm arch_prctl arm_fadvise64_64 bind brk cacheflush capget capset chdir chmod chown chown32 clock_get>
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallErrorNumber=1
LockPersonality=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_INET
RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=no
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
StateDirectoryMode=0755
CacheDirectoryMode=0755
LogsDirectoryMode=0755
ConfigurationDirectoryMode=0755
TimeoutCleanUSec=infinity
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
RestrictSUIDSGID=yes
RestrictNamespaces=yes
MountAPIVFS=no
KeyringMode=private
ProtectProc=invisible
ProcSubset=pid
ProtectHostname=yes
MemoryKSM=no
RootImagePolicy=root=verity+signed+encrypted+unprotected+absent:usr=verity+signed+encrypted+unprotected+absent:home=encrypted+unprotected+absent:srv=encrypted+unprotecte>
MountImagePolicy=root=verity+signed+encrypted+unprotected+absent:usr=verity+signed+encrypted+unprotected+absent:home=encrypted+unprotected+absent:srv=encrypted+unprotect>
ExtensionImagePolicy=root=verity+signed+encrypted+unprotected+absent:usr=verity+signed+encrypted+unprotected+absent:home=encrypted+unprotected+absent:srv=encrypted+unpro>
KillMode=mixed
KillSignal=3
RestartKillSignal=3
FinalKillSignal=9
SendSIGKILL=yes
SendSIGHUP=no
WatchdogSignal=6
Id=nginx.service
Names=nginx.service
Requires=system.slice sysinit.target -.mount
Wants=network-online.target tmp.mount -.mount
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Before=shutdown.target multi-user.target
After=-.mount systemd-journald.socket systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service remote-fs.target basic.target nss-lookup.target sysinit.target network-online.target tmp.mount syste>
RequiresMountsFor=/var/log/nginx
WantsMountsFor=/tmp /var/tmp
Description=nginx web server
LoadState=loaded
ActiveState=failed
FreezerState=running
SubState=failed
FragmentPath=/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
DropInPaths=/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/hardening.conf
UnitFileState=enabled
UnitFilePreset=disabled
StateChangeTimestamp=Sun 2024-09-01 04:15:43 GMT
StateChangeTimestampMonotonic=16855369330
InactiveExitTimestamp=Sun 2024-09-01 04:15:43 GMT
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=16855151427
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Sat 2024-08-31 23:35:22 GMT
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=33880296
ActiveExitTimestamp=Sun 2024-09-01 03:36:55 GMT
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=14526916630
InactiveEnterTimestamp=Sun 2024-09-01 04:15:43 GMT
InactiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=16855369330
CanStart=yes
CanStop=yes
CanReload=yes
CanIsolate=no
CanFreeze=yes
StopWhenUnneeded=no
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no
AllowIsolate=no
DefaultDependencies=yes
SurviveFinalKillSignal=no
OnSuccessJobMode=fail
OnFailureJobMode=replace
IgnoreOnIsolate=no
NeedDaemonReload=no
JobTimeoutUSec=infinity
JobRunningTimeoutUSec=infinity
JobTimeoutAction=none
ConditionResult=yes
AssertResult=yes
ConditionTimestamp=Sun 2024-09-01 04:15:40 GMT
ConditionTimestampMonotonic=16851474435
AssertTimestamp=Sun 2024-09-01 04:15:40 GMT
AssertTimestampMonotonic=16851474442
Transient=no
Perpetual=no
StartLimitIntervalUSec=10s
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitAction=none
FailureAction=none
SuccessAction=none
InvocationID=f4bc801c7ac1461895f4260816e03191
CollectMode=inactive

already tried, without success, to unblock: no PrivateNetwork, no RestrictAddressFamilies, and most other network things.
The only think that will fix this is running the unit as root (i.e. removing User=http). Why is that so if the user does have permission to open ports otherwise?

Does the distribution you're running this on have a supplemental security system, like SELinux or AppArmor?
(RedHat/Fedora have SELinux enabled by default, while Debian/Ubuntu and related distributions might use AppArmor)
It might restrict the http user to standard HTTP/HTTPS ports only by default, and you'll need to add any other ports to the allowed list.
For SELinux, the command you'll need would probably be:
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8000

For AppArmor, strict per-port restrictions seem to be fairly uncommon, but you can use the aa-status command to see if there is an AppArmor profile in effect for the nginx binary.

Thanks for the suggestion. it does have those, but i did disabled selinux and apparmor for this particular case. I do mention it on the question.

It's a combination of me being tired and SystemD abysmal naming conventions and tooling... everything turns into a cat and mouse game. Sigh.
My service file start running the service as root with network Bind capabilities. And I migrated it little by little to be locked down as it is on the question above. But I left one piece from the earlier setup:
SocketBindDeny=any
SocketBindAllow=tcp:80

Still not 100% sure how it is implemented. I might be wrong, but I also do not think that was even working before I added PrivateNetwork=yes. Anyway, that was the root cause. it shows up as a regular access denied as if a regular user tried to open an priviledged port, despite it being an unpriviledge one.

If I remember correctly, it is implemented through seccomp (syscall parameter filter).
